# Does my application support 64 bit? (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, 64-bit, xcode8

64 bit architecture (IOS)

How do I know if my application supports **64bit**? (Photo 2)

Is there any information on this in the photo? (Photo 2)

[**Photo 2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKWDy.png)

The application will support IOS 8.1 and above? (Photo 3)

[**Photo 3**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3H6Q.png)

**Xcode 8.3.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these steps to make sure (look at the picture):

**1)** **Open project "Build Settings"**

**2)** **Select "All"**

**3)** **Look at the "Architectures".**

**There should be "arm64"** (inside Standard architectures (..., arm64) ).

**It means your app supports 64 bit!**

[image]

"The application will support IOS 8.1 and above?" -
**Yes, it will.**